# Конфиденциальность в Service Desk

Tags: безопасность, проектирование

disclaimer: Возможно, вопрос покажется слегка холиварным, но все же.

---

Сопровождаю самописную тикетную систему, но при её проектировании не было учтено, что у некоторых заказчиков иногда бывают тикеты, содержащие коммерческую тайну. Сейчас любой пользователь может прочесть текст любого тикета, который находится в работе, и в связи с этим встала задача как-то организовать конфиденциальность некоторых тикетов.

Как вообще в ITSM организована работа с конфиденциальной информацией? Как можно правильно разрешить сложившуюся ситуацию?

Comment: например отображать заявки только тем пользователям которым они адресованы

Comment: @Bald по ТЗ так нельзя, процесс работы сервисной службы должен быть прозрачен и контролироваться и заказчиком, и исполнителем, и начальником исполнителя, и начальником заказчика, и человеком, который заказчик, когда заказчик ушел в отпуск, и т.д.

Comment: ну так и разрешайте просмотр ***необходимых*** заявок только ***необходимому*** кругу лиц доступ для *контроля*, т.е. заказчик видит все свои заявки, исполнитель видит заявки которые адресованы только ему, начальник исполнителя видит все заявки которые адресованы в его подразделение ну и т.д. или даже больше исполнителю показывать только текущий статус заявки для большей конфедициальности